# Separation of Variables in Third-Order ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading a textbook recently on Differential Calculus. This author in the textbook showed that they simplified this equation:
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d^3}y}{\mathrm{d}x^3} + 3 \dfrac{\mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + 
\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2 - y = \sin(x)
$$

to:
$$
(x+y)\mathrm{d}y-x\mathrm{d}x = 0
$$

My professor says that they used separation of variables. I have a good idea on how to do separation of variables with first order ODEs, but I've never gotten around to testing it on higher orders. Where do I start with this?

**Update:** Turns out they were unrelated. My apologies, I'm good now! Please ignore this

Comment: What book was this in? Did they show any of the steps of the simplification or just jump directly between the two?

Comment: Advanced Engineering Mathematics (With MATLAB) by Dean Dully. There are no steps listed; just the jump between the two. Sorry, I forgot to add that fact.

Comment: I found the passage in the book. These equations are unrelated. The author was listing examples of a 3rd order ODE, a 1st order ODE, and a 4th order PDE. It is unlikely that this differential equation can be solved in closed form, let alone by separation of variables. Higher order nonlinear equations generally don't have closed form solutions.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I thought it was an arbitrary example; must've misread it. I also noticed the separation of variables section just a couple pages over. I might have skipped that one too on accident. Thanks a bunch mate, that cleared things up